# How to format individual gridview cells using css?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Is it possible to format individual cells using CSS in a gridview

I'm using `visual studio 2010` with `vb`

I want to do the following. Based on this table structure...

```
H1 H2 H3 H4
R1 i1 i2 i3
R2 j1 j2 j3
R3 k1 k2 k3
```

I need the following formants:

```
H1, H2, H3, H4 - Headings: bold, white font, blue background
R1, R2, R3- Bold => Row headings
i1, i2 - percentage
i3 - format number with 'pp' at the end, for example 10pp
j1, j2, j3 - mumber
k1, k2, k3 - percentage
```

Any hint/ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more? I dont think that I understand it. What is R1-3 and the rest?

Comment: I've edited question. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: I've abandoned the approch of using CSS and I've resolved the problem by creating a datatable and adding adding % and pp(percentage points) when needed. The problem is that you can not change the data type in datables, so I had to add new columns and format them as string beforehand. Afterwards I deleted the columns that I didn't need. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your question.

From what I get, you are trying to style those elements. One approach would be to add classes to the "td" and then styling those classes. The other would be to add the styles "in-line", on the tags themselves.

As for the "%" and "pp", you could use CSS3's ":after" and put it as its content. But that's not a really good idea. Those should really be generated from the back-end, and not from the CSS.